# Where is the content of resp.Body stored?

Tags: go, interface

I did a simple url retriever today.

```
1 resp, _ := http.Get("http://www.yahoo.com")
2 text, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
3 resp.Body.Close()
4 fmt.Printf("%s", text)
```

The result was printed out as expected. However, I don't understand why it works.

My understanding from line 2 `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` returns []bytes which feeds to 'text' variable.

but:

- resp is a *http.Response struct
- resp.Body is an io.ReadCloser interface
- io.ReadCloser implements io.Reader and io.Closer interfaces
- io.Reader signature is (p []byte) (n int, err error)

So, where were those content of resp.Body stored? (as oppose to my current acceptance that Body's content came 'magically' from somewhere)

Comment: The response body is streamed on-demand as the Body field is read. see here https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#Response.Body

Comment: It's not stored anywhere. It is read from the network.

Comment: Thank you @Eklavya and Flimzy. I start to understand a bit more and corrected my understanding of content being stored, it's actually streamed. The end-to-end from request to getting remote content still needs some tracing and investigation. But really thanks for shining me a light to the direction where I can further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eklayvya mentioned in the comments the response Body is streamed on-demand. But to add a little more context. When you call `http.Get()`. The `Get()` function in the `http/client` package initializes an `http.DefaultClient` that creates the request on your behalf with default HTTP Headers and metadata.

Actually a peek into the source code reveals that `Get` is just a wrapper around the more common `http.NewRequest()` function that creates a new HTTP request. The request is created by an underlying call to `http.Do(req *Request)` that takes in the request, performs additional formatting, then sends the request to the server in question.

For more details, there is a `func send(ireq *Request, rt RoundTripper, deadline time.Time)` in the `http/client.go` file that actually performs the http request. If you note from the function signature, it uses your request, and a 2nd argument called a `RoundTripper`. This is where things get a bit more interesting.

```
// https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go (line 117)
// RoundTripper is an interface representing the ability to execute a
// single HTTP transaction, obtaining the Response for a given Request.
//
// A RoundTripper must be safe for concurrent use by multiple
// goroutines.
type RoundTripper interface {
    ...
    RoundTrip(*Request) (*Response, error)
}
```

`RoundTrip` takes in a `Request` and returns a `Response` containing the body. Here is where the network streams the bytes for the `response.Body` hence your ability to receive the `[]byte` from the network. The implementation of the `RoundTripper` interface is left up to the requirements of the caller. In this case it is the `http.DefaultClient`. However you can override this and do what you want with it.

Several network libraries do implement this interface. An example is the `ClientConn` struct from the `golang.org/x/net/http2` package. Line 970 contains the implementation of a `RoundTrip` with the body being written to it. The implementation is quite complex as it caters for concurrency, as well as timeouts and other network considerations. You can take a look if interested.

Here is the [blob](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/http2/transport.go#L408)

Comment: Thank you @martinomburajr, you really nailed the whole process and I'm looking at RoundTripper now. Amazing how you did all the tracing work to figure this out.

Comment: I just follow the trail using my IDE and read the code. It's awesome the go team have it all out there in the open! The `net` package in general is very detailed, but if you want to learn how network requests are made in their entirety (up until Layer-2) it's a good place to start.